# Помогите со вьюхами

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток, нужна помощь. Помогите создать вьюхи.
Есть форма документа, в ней 3 параметра: **Тип продукта**, **Продукт**, **Брэнд продукта**.
Форма должна позволять добавлять разные марки одного и того же продукта одновременно.

То есть должно быть что - то наподобие этого:

1. Поле: Тип Продукта
2. Поле: Продукт
3. Поле: Брэнд продукта
4. Ссылка на добавление нового Брэнда, то есть link_to_add_association
   :brand того же самого Продукта пункте 2

Новичек в Rails , поэтому не судите строго, спасибо заранее за помощь.

Ниже логика приложения:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base (id, name)
  has_many :product_documents  
end

class BrandOfProductDocument < ActiveRecord::Base (id, product_id, document_id)
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :brand_of_product
end 

class BrandOfProduct < ActiveRecord::Base (id, brand_id, product_id)
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :product
end 

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base (id, name, product_type_id)
  belongs_to :product_type
end 

class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base (id, name)

end 

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base (id, name)

end
```

Document_form.rb:

```
class DocumentForm < ActiveForm::Base
  self.main_model = :document

  association brand_of_product_document do 
    attribute :brand_of_product_id    
    association :brand_of_product do       
      association :product do 
        attribute :name         
        association :product_type do    
          attribute :name 
        end 
      end
      association :brand do     
        attribute :name   
      end  
    end
  end   
end
```

**ActiveForm::Base**  это из гема **actionform**

А вот сам интерфейс формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если быть конкретнее, то проблемы с ассоциациям во вьюхе, как правильно построить,
попытался следовать вот этому примеру https://github.com/m-Peter/nested-form-examples/tree/master/full-example/after/app/views/projects.

В файле **_form.html.erb** пишу:

```
<div id="tags">
  <%= f.fields_for :brand_of_product_document do |bpd| %>
    <%= render 'brand_of_product_document_fields', :f => bpd%>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add brand_of_product_doc', f, :brand_of_product_document  %>
</div>
```

В файле **_brand_of_product_document_fields.html.erb** что писать не понятно,
так как мой случай не совсем схож с вышеуказанным примером.

Comment: 1. `ActiveForm::Base` - это из какого гема?
2. `Форма должна позволять добавлять разные марки одного и того же продукта одновременно.` Можно про это подробнее? Хотябы можно схематично нарисовать форму.
3. Извечный вопрос. Что **конкретно** не получается?

Comment: Вот добавил инфу, постарался как можно подробнее изложить :)

Comment: Люди добрые отзовитесь, направьте меня по правильному пути

Comment: Практически любое решение в Rails с редактированием нескольких моделей сразу это весьма объёмный и некрасивый костыль, в первую очередь потому, что требует дополнительных мер на клиенте. Что в свою очередь напрашивается на чисто-клиентское решение и API-подобную серверную часть. Это просто гораздо проще сделать и осознать, хотя и требует ознакомиться с бОльшим числом технологий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, не знаю такого гема, как `actionform`. Сейчас нашёл его на гитхабе, но он странный. Я бы не рекомендовал им пользоваться.

В вопросе я так до конца и не разобрался с ассоциациями. Думаю, того что понял должно хватить для ответа, но извиняюсь, если, всё же, уйду в сторону.

Не нужно стараться воспроизводить структуру БД на форме. Форма должна быть плоской, даже если она изменяет данные в 10 таблицах. Просто это дополнительная путаница.
Реализовать такую форму поможет `FormObject`. (Кстати, даже в [стайлгайтдах](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#model-classes) рекомендуют ими пользоваться)

```
class DocumentForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include Virtus.model

  def self.model_name
    Document.model_name
  end

  attribute :product_type_id
  attribute :product_id
  attribute :brand_ids, Array

  # Тут можно писать валидации какие нужны. Например так:
  validates :product_type_id, presence: true
  validates :product_id, presence: true

  def persisted?
    # Пример только для создания
    # для редактирования потребуется модификация
    false
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?

    document = Document.new
    document.product_type = ProductType.find(product_type_id)
    document.product = document.product_type.products.find(product_id)
    document.brands = Brand.where(id: brand_ids)
    document.save
  end
end
```

В контроллере:

```
def new
  @form = DocumentForm.new
end
def edit
  @form = DocumentForm.new(permitted_params)
  if @form.save
    redirect_to documents_path
  else
    rednder action: :new
  end
end

#...
private
def permitted_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:product_type_id, :product_id, brand_ids: [])
end
```

На вьюхе:

```
<%= form_for @form do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :product_type_id, ProductType.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  <%= form.select :product_type_id, Product.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  <%= form.select :brand_ids, Brand.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

Пример был сделан с использованием [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus). Для того, чтобы обеспечить связанность списоков (выбирать только продукты бренда) и возможность по кнопочке добавлять ещё поля для выбора брендов потребуется пописать / поискать компоненты на JavaScript. Но это уже тянет на отдельный вопрос.